How would I go about differentiating between an issue that lies with the CPU vs one that lies with the RAM vs one that is tied to the Motherboard
My issue is a persistent stutter in games, on desktop, in browsers, in SAFE mode, and in the BIOS. It appears as apparent, severe screen tearing and a back-and-forth jitter. I've tried just about every standard solution to diagnose the issue (monitor, cable, resolution, refresh rate, drivers, BIOS, OS clean install, VGA driver, etc etc) and nothing has worked. At this point, I'm fairly convinced its a hardware issue and I'm planning to swap parts with a friend this weekend to see if I can better isolate the issue. I wanted to post here as in case there was a more specific process I could try in the meantime or even just to gain additional context. I'm good to try just about anything at this point.
From my limited experience and understanding, I believe the issue must lie in between either CPU and RAM or in between the RAM and MOBO/display.
I've posted on both Tom's Hardware and PCHelpForum. I'll link these threads below as they contain additional context (System specs, videos of the behavior, an unresolved Reddit thread of what appears to be the exact same behavior, and a good record of attempted fixes).
https://pchelpforum.net/t/impossible-to-research-persistent-frame-stutter-jitter.90301/
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/hard-to-diagnose-research-persistent-jitter-stutter-and-screen-tearing.3850816/
I truly appreciate any input and time you all can give me.

One more test to confirm if the drive or OS is involved: boot from USB and run for a while. If issue persists, it hardware. You can quickly create a boot USB drive with Ubuntu Live, Hiren’s BootCD PE, both of which have browsers (Firefox) for testing screen stability. If either work, then go back to drivers and OS. Also -- are you overclocking? Intel has found some recent CPU's have issues: https://www.pcmag.com/explainers/intels-raptor-lake-desktop-cpu-bug-what-to-know-what-to-do-now

That's a good idea! I'll give it a shot. I considered the Intel CPU issues, luckily I'm on 12th Gen so it doesn't apply to me

I booted into Ubuntu. If anything the issue seems worse there. How would I go about narrowing down part of Mobo that would be related?

Have you performed standard RAM tests? There are many utilities to do so, such as https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/ and  https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/how-to-test-ram. N.B. Let the test run overnight -- depending on speed and amount, it can take as much as a day, or more.

I've done a few passes with a couple RAM tests. I've also cycled through each RAM stick in the A2 slot. The issue was happening before my current RAM setup. I'll try a MemTest tonight.

In your description, you said the stutter is happening in BIOS.  This means it is a hardware issue.  Remove all but one stick of RAM.  See if it still happens.  If it does, remove that one stick and replace it with another.  Repeat.  If all are stuttering, its likely the GPU that is faulty.  If it works normally, then its that one (or more) RAM module.

Thank you for your response. I've tried cycling my RAM one-at-a-time; no change. I've also tried on my iGPU. Same thing. (Though harder to tell due to lower framerate)
